# Having problem with sum of 6 decimal place value

Tags: jasper-reports

[image]

In this image you can see total of value is **165.190595** but actual total i want is **165.190594**.
Jasper report doing rounding by itself i want to stop rounding of last digit. I have tried pattern but it also not working. also tried this `BigDecimal roundfinalPrice = new gDecimal(5652.256122).setScale(6,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);`

when i tried to use `new BigDecimal("0.1").setScale(6)` it shows rounding is necessary.

Comment: I think you haven't provided enough detail to enable anyone to answer your question. What do you mean "rounding is necessary"? `new BigDecimal("0.1").setScale(6)` works just fine. You also need to show Java code that adds these numbers and gets the last digit wrong.